# Why TypeScript have different generic function inference between arrow function and normal functions?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In following example, TypeScript

```
function test<T = unknown>(options: {
    a: (c: T) => void,
    b: () => T
}) {}

test({
    a: (c) => { c }, // c is number
    b: () => 123
})

test({
    b: () => 123,
    a: (c) => { return c }, // c is number
})

test({
    b() { return 'test' },
    a(c) { return c }, // c is string
})

test({
    a(c) { return c }, // c is unknown, but expected string
    b() { return 'test' }
})
```

I can't understand why these inferences are not same. I don't think there's arrow function/normal function depend on this/execution context.

Comment: If you swap the `a` and `b` in the last test, you'll find it infers `c` as a `string`. As to *why* it does that, I don't know, but it seems related to the ordering.

Comment: Some small corrections about the code, `a: (c: T) => T` and first case missing a `return` in `a`.
Now, I can't provide an answer, but I see that if you hover `b` in the last case, it also says to return `unknown` instead of `string`.

Comment: Methods have a context-dependency on the `this` type so the compiler delays inferring it, which causes the problem you see. Inference works from non-context-dependent values and then left-to-right from context-dependent values. This is all working as expected according to [ms/TS#48538](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48538).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This looks limitation of contextual inference in TypeScript.

Comment: It's not "in progress", it's just still open because it hasn't been completely implemented and might never be.  Where do you see that it's "in progress"?  [ms/TS#48538](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48538) is the work that was done on this sort of thing, and it's complete.

Comment: the issue still being opened. it looks contributors are still discussing. I mean that is work in progress

Comment: There is no indication that anyone is working on this.  Just because an issue is open or that some people are commenting on it, doesn't mean anyone is working on it. The TS GitHub repo has almost 6,000 open issues but most of them are not being actively worked on.  At best this is "not declined", but that doesn't mean much.  It is misleading to call it a "work in progress feature".

Comment: okay. this is not wip.

Comment: So do you want to [edit] this answer then?